# How do I uninstall a Chocolatey package with Ansible?

Tags: powershell, ansible, chocolatey

I have written a simple playbook to uninstall firefox from a virtual machine (VM) running windows10. I am new to ansible/chocolatey so here is the code:

```
- name: Test win_chocolatey module
  hosts: win1
  tasks:
    - name: Uninstall firefox
      win_chocolatey:
        name: firefox
        state: absent
```

After I execute this code on my machine firefox does not appear anymore among the chocolatey packages installed on windows VM. However firefox is still installed and it works properly on the windows VM.

I looked up the ansible documentation for the uninstall command and I have found a note:

".... choco uninstall removes the package from your system only if the script chocolateyUninstall.ps1 is provided by the package maintainer".

So, I have modified my previous playbook in order to include the powershell script I downloaded (https://github.com/Iristyle/ChocolateyPackages/blob/master/HipChat/tools/chocolateyUninstall.ps1):

```
- name: Test win_chocolatey module
  hosts: win1
  tasks:
    - name: Run PS script
      script: /home/ansible_example/chocolateyUninstall.ps1
    - name: Uninstall firefox
      win_chocolatey:
        name: firefox
        state: absent
```

Still firefox is not gone on my windows VM. 
I am using ansible 2.0.0.2, chocolatey 0.9.9.11

Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Each package on Chocolatey.org would require it's own chocolateyUninstall.ps1 file.  You can't use another package's chocolateyUninstall.ps1 file and hope that it will uninstall another package, that simply isn't how it is designed to work.

As you can see [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Firefox#files) the Firefox package on Chocolatey.org indeed does not have an uninstall file, therefore, ansible can't call it.

What you might want to try is using the "new" auto-uninstallation feature that is available in Chocolatey.  You can find out more information about this using:

`choco feature -h`

After enabling that feature, install Firefox again, and then try uninstalling it, and see if that has the desired result.

Also, it is probably worth testing this without ansible in the equation.  Test it directly with Chocolatey, make sure this works, then add in ansible.

Comment: I installed firefox again, then run: - choco feature enable -n autoUninstaller followed by -choco uninstall firefox. Unfortunately that does not help: firefox is still installed in my windows VM.

Comment: I have uninstalled manually firefox, then installed again (when the new feature autoUninstaller was already on) with chocolatey and finally uninstalled with chocolatey. Now it works fine!

Comment: Well, I tried to run the same "install/uninstall" routine through Ansible and that does not work. It may be because of the pop up firefox windows which shows up when I run  "install/uninstall" with chocolatey. Is there a reason why such a commune package like Firefox does not have the chocolateyUninstall.ps1 file yet?

Comment: @diegus yes, that sounds correct.  Please note in the above, I mentioned that you should install again after you enabled the feature.  Chocolatey stores some information during the installation that is required, and this is only done when the feature is enabled.

Comment: @diegus are you saying that the install/uninstall through Chocolatey is not silent?  i.e. you have to perform some interaction (clicking options, etc).  Now that Chocolatey has the auto uninstaller feature, a chocolateyUninstall.ps1 file is not a requirement for a package.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark "this is only done when the feature is enabled" - this is incorrect. Choco always stores the information, however if the application was already installed, choco may not detect a difference for the registry snapshot.

Comment: @ferventcoder ah, gotcha! I knew there was something that could happen during the installation that could cause issues.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @ GaryEwanPark Yes, the uninstall is not silent with chocolatey. It may be because of that the uninstalling procedure of Firefox from the system with Ansible cannot be performed. This is why I asked you about the chocolateyUninstall.ps1 file, can this solve the problem?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark might be worth it to update this answer, but as of `Choco 0.9.9+` the feature is [enabled by default](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/uninstall). This is especially important to note when you are developing your own package, you may not need to provide a `chocolateyUninstall.ps1` (though it will still get executed in the case the auto-uninstaller is enabled). I have written several internal packages for our organization and I've only needed to provide uninstall scripts in one special case where I manually remove a batch script the package creates during install.